# Galaxy Note 10.1 multiscreen api?

Tags: android

Galaxy Note 10.1 supports running multiple applications on single screen basically splitting it in half. This is only available for a limited set of samsung apps. I couldn't find any SDK or API to support that in my application, is there any way to simulate that?

This is what I am talking about: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBii6rp5YNg

Comment: May be [this][1] link would help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android

Answer (score 1):

I've got some information from a Sammy related guy.

I don't know detail.

But he told that it supported by manifest file's category.
There is no special API.

I think you can find method through analyzing decompiled manifest files.

Actually this is a story of the Galaxy Note 2's multiview.
But I guess Galaxy Note 10.1's technology and this are same.

Answer (score 0):

Following link talk about having a button always on top of all views:

[Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android)

May be this would help you in getting footing view for your app.

Comment: Thank you it's a nice trick, however I mean a device specific functionality like shown here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBii6rp5YNg

Comment: It is not part of standard android SDK and I don't think Samsung has any plan to push that code in open source android SDK or to provide SDK for their devices..

So for now I guess system overlay is the best that we got unless you want to update the source code..

Comment: I was hoping to do that specifically for the Note device, not all Android platforms.